# Entity Framework - Correct way to check for single records before using them

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

To get a LIST of records I normally do something along the lines of:

```
var efCompany = from a in _dbRiv.Company where a.CompanyId == companyFeedInfo.CompanyId select a;
```

To get a single record, when I know I am using the PK to retrieve it, I use something like:

```
var efCompany = (from a in _dbRiv.Company where a.CompanyId == companyFeedInfo.CompanyId select a).First();
```

Now, using the single record approach, if the PK is a faulty value (like it purposefully is in testing) the 2nd line throws an error.

What is the **best practice** way of getting a single record and dealing with it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `SingleOrDefault` if you expect 0 or 1, or `FirstOrDefault` if you just need the first record out of potentially many, but can cope with 0. Both will return the default value for the type (usually null) if there are no results.

By the way, queries like this are generally more readable (IMO) *without* using a query expression, so you might have something like:

```
var efCompany = _dbRiv.Company
                      .Where(a => a.CompanyId == companyFeedInfo.CompanyId)
                      .SingleOrDefault();

if (efCompany != null)
{
    // Use it
}
else
{
    // Report to user, or whatever
}
```

Query expressions are great when you're using multiple operators, or doing relatively complex things like joins - but if you've *just* got a `where` clause or *just* got a projection, this "dot notation" is simpler IMO. It also works better when you need to call a method like `FirstOrDefault` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comment on query expressions.  Still learning a lot on EF and my mind does not entirely wrap around the lambda syntax.  Reminds me a lot of old C memory pointers.  ;)

Comment: `SingleOrDefault` is supported in EF 4, but not in EF 1. `FirstOrDefault` is supported in both.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Whats the difference between placing the order backwords on the LINQ chain... ex. `_db.MyModels.Where(a => a.Prop == "value").SingleOrDefault();` versus `_db.MyModels.SingleOrDefault().Where(a => a.Prop == "value");` - Performances? Excecution order? etc...

Comment: @one.beat.consumer: The second won't even compile (in general), as SingleOrDefault returns a single value, not a sequence. But if it *did* compile, it wouldn't do what you wanted. It would check that there's only one value *in the whole MyModels table*, then apply the filter to it.

Comment: @JonSkeet I realized that right after I typed it. How about this: `_db.Models.Select(model => new ViewModel{ Prop = model.Prop }).ToList().Where(viewModel => viewModel.Prop = "value");` versus `_db.Models.Select(model => new ViewModel{ Prop = model.Prop }).Where(viewModel => viewModel.Prop = "value").ToList();` -- what are the implications of these different? any performance differences? database activity? casting issues? just curious

Comment: @one.beat.consumer: Calling `ToList` will force all the results to come back to the client, at which point LINQ to Objects will take over... vs performing the query at the database, which is obviously more efficient.

Answer (score 8):

Note that both [`SingleOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx) and  [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) will not allow you to specify the default value.

There's [`DefaultIfEmpty()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx), which allows you to specify the default value you want returned if there are no items in the enumerable. You can combine this one with `First()` (as in `DefaultIfEmpty().First()`) to achieve `FirstOrDefault()`-like behavior and a lambda to wrap creating a new instance and adding it to the set.

If you just need to check for the existence of a record, you can also use [`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx). However, this will result in two queries, if you need to process the record if it exists.

Comment: Any() is the the best way to go if you just need to check the existence.

Comment: `DefaultIfEmpty`, like `SingleOrDefault`, is supported in EF 4 but not EF 1.

Comment: I know this is 8 years old now but any chance of an example?

Comment: @Cloud sorry, I haven't touched any Microsoft technologies in the last seven years or so, so... :-/

Comment: if (yourDataTable.Any()) { }

if (yourDataTable.Any(x => x.Field == True || x.OtherField == "Test") { }

@Cloud is this the example you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

```
var efCompany = _dbRiv.Company
                  .SingleOrDefault(a => a.CompanyId == companyFeedInfo.CompanyId);

if (efCompany != null)
{
    // Use it
}
else
{
    // Report to user, or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
_dbRiv.Company.find(#id)
```

if you are looking for a record without its included models.

Or

```
_dbRiv.Company.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == #id);
```

I recommend FirstOrDefault over SingleOrDefault because of the performance. With SingleOrDefault it needs to scan the entire table and make sure there is only one record with the Id. With FirstOrDefault it can simply go until it finds that id then stop. On a large table it will save you small amounts of time with each query.

Also you can use AsNoTracking to improve memory consumption if you don't need to track any changes made to the model. For instance if you are returning it via a rest request without calling save.

Comment: I'm guessing that it if there's an index it would not need to scan the whole table.