# Always returning not null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a controller where if the specific data doesn't exist it will create a new row otherwise it will return an alert that the data is already existing.
The problem is that I have a query where it always say not null even my table is empty.

controller:

```
 public ActionResult CreateDisease(int? diseaseID, int? assessmentID, DiseaseList diseaselist)
    {
        var data = from x in db.DiseaseLists where ((x.AssessmentID == assessmentID) && (x.DiseaseID == diseaseID)) select x;

        if (data == null)
        {
            diseaselist.DiseaseID = diseaseID;
            diseaselist.AssessmentID = assessmentID;
            db.DiseaseLists.Add(diseaselist);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("Already Exist", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

Comment: It will never be `null`, just empty

Comment: So, set a breakpoint and inspect your variables? You need to check if `data.Any()`, not if it's null, which is explained in plenty of other questions. Please read [ask].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142597/entity-framework-correct-way-to-check-for-single-records-before-using-them

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks.

Comment: @CodeCaster this solved my problem.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your data will not be `null`, it will only be an empty list. Change your code to this to check if the object you are looking for is found.

```
public ActionResult CreateDisease(int? diseaseID, int? assessmentID, DiseaseList diseaselist)
    {
        var data = from x in db.DiseaseLists where ((x.AssessmentID == assessmentID) && (x.DiseaseID == diseaseID)) select x;

        if (!data.Any())
        {
            diseaselist.DiseaseID = diseaseID;
            diseaselist.AssessmentID = assessmentID;
            db.DiseaseLists.Add(diseaselist);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json("Already Exist", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

as Stephen Muecke said in the comment above, it will never be null, just empty and that is why it keeps returning an object so I tried CodeCaster's suggestion and it works perfectly.

instead of

```
var data = from x in db.DiseaseLists where ((x.AssessmentID == assessmentID) && (x.DiseaseID == diseaseID)) select x;
```

I tried

```
var data = db.DiseaseLists.Where(x => (x.AssessmentID == assessmentID) && (x.DiseaseID == diseaseID)).SingleOrDefault();
```

and it works perfectly.